# Wordpress вложенные пункты меню консоли

Tags: wordpress

Вот хоть убей, не пойму как организовать такую схему в админке:

```
Пункт меню
  -тип записи
  -тип записи
```

Типы записи добавляю через `register_post_type`, а как получившийся раздел засунуть в произвольный пункт меню?

Comment: Справа вверху в меню - настройки экрана - оно? Или что/где надо? О каком "меню" речь?

Comment: Главном меню  в консоли. Справа которое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См функции [add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) и [add_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)
По русски:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_menu_page
https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_submenu_page

```
add_menu_page( string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '', string $icon_url = '', int $position = null )
```

Позиция в меню (`$position`):

```
2 – Dashboard
4 – Separator
5 – Posts
10 – Media
15 – Links
20 – Pages
25 – Comments
59 – Separator
60 – Appearance
65 – Plugins
70 – Users
75 – Tools
80 – Settings
99 – Separator
```

Добавка. Использование:

```
add_menu_page('Основное доп. меню', 'Мое основное меню', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug');

add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'Основное доп. меню', 'Мое основное меню', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-slug');

add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-slug', 'Мое подменю', 'Страница настроек моего подменю', 'manage_options', 'my-secondary-slug', 'page_callback_function');
```

Добавка 2.
в `register_post_type` должны ть указаны `show_ui` и `show_in_menu`

Comment: Это я знаю, а как использовать?

Comment: В см? А что не понятно-то? Там же и примеры есть.

Comment: Ну так и как это использовать? 
Покажите пожалуйста...

Comment: То что вы добавили я сделать могу. У меня вопрос в том как мне в подменю запихнуть  register_post_type

Comment: Я воще не понимаю зачем было это ОТКЛЮЧАТЬ в register_post_type. Дефолтно всё выводится. Сгенеруруй уже что ли кастомные типы https://generatewp.com/post-type/

Comment: Блин... Вы не поняли вопроса похоже. )) 
Я добавляю пункт меню, кастомный, в котором ничего нет, 

У меня есть 2-3-5-10 кастомных типов записей. 
Так вот мне нужно чтобы они были не в основном меню, а спрятаны в этом, добавленном ранее кастомном меню.

Comment: Блин.. всё уже перечислено. 2 РАЗНЫХ способа показаны.