# add_menu_page как ссылка на редактирование страницы

Tags: wordpress

Собственно вопрос - как сделать, чтобы добавленный пункт меню через `add_menu_page` вёл на редактирование страницы `/post.php?post=178&action=edit` ?

Comment: Судя по [прошлому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666490/wordpress-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8) не правильно созданы кастомные типы. Нужно просто их создать правильно и всё в меню будет. И не нужно никаких add_menu_page.

Comment: Нужно) Мне нужно сгруппировать несколько кастомных типов, которые относятся к определённым страница сайта. Скгрупировать получилось, но теперь выходит что название главного пункта меню - пустой раздел

Comment: Я не знаю как именно "сгруппировать", но не вижу проблем это сделать при создании кастомных типов. Более того - если сгруппировать надо, поломав стандартную логику вывода (это можно конечно сделать), то это говорит о большой вероятности неправильного проектирования сайта.

Comment: _После ответа @KAGGDesign._ Хм.. Я наверное не понял задачу и нужно именно ОДНУ конкретную страницу в меню вывести? Или же всё же ссылки на редактирование всех кастомных типов (ну как стандартно записи-страницы)? Если первое, тогда ответ коллеги то, что нужно.

Comment: @SeVlad Вопрос туманен, как обычно. Но если нужно n страниц вывести, то можно их в массив запихнуть, ну а в foreach то, что я написал...

Comment: @KAGGDesign я просто подумал, что речь о стандартно получающемся выводе пунктов меню кастомных типов, который почему-то был потерян при их создании  (ну мне так показалось ещё с прошлого вопроса ТСа). Ну а если это не так, то да, согласен с ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так в functions.php:

```
function edit_post_item() {
  // $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $callback_function
  add_posts_page(__('Edit My Page'), __('Edit My Page'), 'read', 'edit.php?post=178&action=edit');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'edit_post_item');
```